# IntelliJ build artifacts with invalid byte in build.xml

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx

I'm trying to build artifacts of my javaFx application in IntelliJ but is always giving the following error:

```
Error:Java FX Packager: 
BUILD FAILED
Error reading project file E:\intelliJuserHome\compile-server\app_farmo_b1d2d5a4\_temp_\build.xml: Invalid byte 2 of 4-byte UTF-8 sequence.
Total time: 0 seconds
Error:Java FX Packager: fx:deploy task has failed.
```

I already moved my user home to this one because of the encoding (I saw someone suggesting this) but didn't work.

Someone knows how to fix this?

thank you

Comment: Try to delete `E:\intelliJuserHome\compile-server\app_farmo_b1d2d5a4` folder and specify the `UTF-8` encoding Settings | Editor | File Encodings for project.

Comment: I already did that and did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did found what was wrong. The title had special characters

Comment: Same, but in the user folder, which was "Carlos López".

Comment: what title? where you chaged it?